# Sqlite database getting locked

Tags: python, sqlite

I have a sqlite database in my local drive. There are few schema in there which I want to use to create a combined table

My initial Python connection to Sqlite was as below:

```
import sqlite3

# Create a SQL connection to our SQLite database
con = sqlite3.connect("dataset.sqlite")

cur = con.cursor()
```

I do this to execute the sql on the database and create a table

```
sql= """

create table IF NOT EXISTS requests_user_info as 
select a.request_id, a.user_id,b.email, a.category_id,c.name as category_name, 
 a.location_id, d.name as location_name,a.creation_time as Request_time
 from requests as a
 left join 
 users as b
 left join 
 categories as c
 left join 
 locations as d
 on a.user_id=b.user_id
 and 
 a.category_id=c.category_id
 and 
 a.location_id=d.location_id

"""

cur.execute(sql)
```

But it keeps running and doesn't seem to end. So then I thought of directly accessing the sqlite database in Terminal

I start sqlite db in terminal as

```
sqlite3 dataset.sqlite
```

It gets access to the database. However when I run the same query without the python part, the cursor keeps blinking and never stops.

Later I check from another terminal window that the database has been locked. The table also doesn't get created. Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Try with this sql `create table IF NOT EXISTS requests_user_info as 
select a.request_id, a.user_id,b.email, a.category_id,c.name as category_name, 
 a.location_id, d.name as location_name,a.creation_time as Request_time
 from requests as a
 left join 
 users as b on a.user_id=b.user_id
 left join 
 categories as c on a.category_id=c.category_id
 left join 
 locations as d on a.location_id=d.location_id`

Comment: Aah.. using sql after long time and did some stupid mistake.